# Mounting heavy items with no studs

Tags: drywall, mounting, brackets, mount

I purchased this [wine rack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017OI08YI) even though I'm skeptical on the strength of the L Brackets.

[image: wine rack]

I do not have studs in my wall but purchased these [heavy duty anchors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051IB94C) for 3/8 inch drywall.

[image: toggle bolts]

Any thoughts on whether this will work or not? I've never done this before so am very skeptical. Any other tips or tricks would be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have studs in your wall, what do you have? It's generally studs or brick / concrete, and if you've got brick or concrete, those togglers likely won't work...

Comment: And are you sure your drywall is 3/8"? That's an extremely uncommon size.

Comment: I live in a condo so it seems in this position that it's just hollow but with some areas having metal studs. Are metal studs a thing?

Comment: I'm not 100% if it is 3/8" but it looked less wide than 1/2 inch. The condo unit was built in 2002 so maybe 1/2 was more common then. thanks for all the feedback :)

Comment: Consult with maintenance, then.  They have the experience to know what works on their walls, and what does not.  You can't replace that kind of experience with opinions on the Internet, no matter how qualified.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, those should work, as long as you have a hollow space behind the drywall. You should not load up the wine rack completely, though. The weight rating on those is 143 lb in 1/2" drywall; since you've got 3/8" drywall, that rating decreases to 97 lb.

The weight of the unit is 24 lb, and it says each shelf can hold 35 lb. All together, that's 94 lb (and does that include the glassware on the bottom?). You'll have 2 of the anchors, yes, but I wouldn't want to load 90+ lbs on toggle bolts - I just wouldn't trust the drywall that much. Any un-level installation or uneven loading would skew those numbers, so I'd stick to keeping it half full or less (hey, drink more wine!).

As an alternative, could you mount a piece of 1/2" plywood to the wall, hitting studs, and then mount the wine rack to the plywood? If your wall doesn't have studs, what does it have?

Comment: 5 bottles doesn't add up to anywhere near 35 lbs, though. I'd figure (conservatively) 4 lbs. each, bringing the total down to around 65 lbs. Four of those anchors would do fine in half-inch drywall. I have doubts that the OP actually has 3/8. If it is, I'd use six anchors.

Comment: Six 1.5 L bottles of wine weigh around 40 lb, so 5 of those would be very close to the 35 lb limit. May not be able to fit 5 of those on a single shelf though, but there are all kinds of differently-shaped bottles out there.

Comment: Nearly all are 750ml. I'm going to trust our OP to not load it up with magnums. :)

Comment: It may be 1/2 inch, i'll have to double check., thank you all for the helpful feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

The rack is 28 inches wide. Its bound to be over at least one stud. How did you try to locate? Did you use a good stud finder? Look for hints for where a stud might be, like an electrical outlet below. (electrical boxes are usually mounted on a stud). Also a magnetic stud finder would find nails and screws. I would try again to find at least one stud and attach the rack to that with two screws, and use steel toggle bolts for the other two into drywall.